# UITextSelectionView name unrecognized selector using SpriteKit and UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, sprite-kit, uitextview

I have an app that worked perfectly fine with iOS 8.0, until the switch to 8.1. When I create a UITextView inside of a SpriteKit game I get the following error:

```
-[UITextSelectionView name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f96ee6bdfa0
```

This occurs if I create the object in code or place a UITextView in my xib file.

The hierarchy looks like this:

UIViewController (self.view is a SKView) -> UIView -> UITextView

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UITextView *test = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Any ideas what the problem might be and why it appeared so suddenly?

Comment: What happens when you enable Zombie Objects?

Comment: It doesn't say anything.

Comment: And where is your exception stack trace?

Comment: That one line is the only stack trace I get in the console. The program crashes on line: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: This really sounds like an uninitialized memory problem. They are the hardest to track down. Is all your code Obj-C or are you using some C/C++ in it?

Comment: I am also facing same problem..please post the answer if you get solution...Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem ended up being the use of performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: within a SpriteKit scene. Once I replaced these occurrences with an SKAction, it solved the UITextView problem.

Old Code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

New Code:

```
SKAction *action   = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(methodName) onTarget:self];
SKAction *wait     = [SKAction waitForDuration:1.0];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, action]];
[self runAction:sequence];
```

Comment: Hey, great hint! One question though. Do you think, if i call performSelector within an SKScene, but on a UIKit object, it will still cause an issue? I can't seem to be able to recreate the crash myself..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a crash turning up in iOS 8.1. But instead of crashing when calling [UITextSelectionView name] the log tells me that it crashes on [GKLocalPlayerInternal name] instead.

And strangely enough the problem disappears when I replace [self performSelector...] (where self is a SKNode) with doing the same with [SKAction performSelector...].

Seems to be a not too obvious bug in iOS 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution what works.

```
UITextView *textView = [UITextView .....];   
**textView.selectable = NO;**
```